# How is "this" set when calling array.map?

Tags: typescript, this

I'm trying to figure out how 'this' is bound when passing a function to the `map` method of an array.

I have the following code (which you can [see on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mtvw4g)):

```
import './style.css';

class Foo {
  public method() { return this ? `"this" is a ${this.constructor.name}`
                                : '"this" is undefined'; }
}

class Caller {
  public method1(array) {
    return array.map(function() { return foo.method(); });
  }
  public method2(array) {
    return array.map(this.callMethod);
  }
  public method3(array) {
    return array.map(foo.method);
  }
  public method4(array) {
    return array.map(v => foo.method());
  }
  private callMethod() { return foo.method(); }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const caller = new Caller();
const array = [1];

document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = `
  <dl>
    <dt>Expected</dt>
    <dd>${foo.method()}</dd>
    <dt>Method 1 (anonymous function)</dt>
    <dd>${caller.method1(array)}</dd>
    <dt>Method 2 (class method)</dt>
    <dd>${caller.method2(array)}</dd>
    <dt>Method 3 (function reference)</dt>
    <dd>${caller.method3(array)}</dd>
    <dt>Method 4 (lambda function)</dt>
    <dd>${caller.method4(array)}</dd>
  </dl>
`;
```

This gives the following output:

> ```
> Expected
>   "this" is a Foo
> Method 1 (anonymous function)
>   "this" is a Foo
> Method 2 (class method)
>   "this" is a Foo
> Method 3 (function reference)
>   "this" is undefined
> Method 4 (lambda function)
>   "this" is a Foo
> ```

So, in all cases except when referencing the function member directly, the `method` method is called with `this` bound to the `Foo` object.

I can't square this with the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description) of `array.prototype.map` on MDN, which says:

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be used as callback's this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value.

In none of those cases above am I explicitly providing a `thisArg` parameter, so why do 3 of the 4 methods "work"?

PS. Bonus question: why, if I comment out the first line (`import './style.css'`) does this make method 3 suddenly work as well?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In none of those cases above am I explicitly providing a thisArg parameter, so why do 3 of the 4 methods "work"?

You aren't providing `thisArg` parameter for `map` callback, **but** you are not testing `this` in the `map` callback, you are testing `this` in a `Foo.method` which in all 3 these methods is called as

```
foo.method()
```

which guarantees that inside a `method` this will be `foo` (and it has nothing to do with map specifically, that's how calling a method with `.` operator behaves in general).

> PS. Bonus question: why, if I comment out the first line (import './style.css') does this make method 3 suddenly work as well?!!

That's not what I'm seeing. This is what's printed when I remove `import` statement:

```
"this" is a Window
```

which is consistent with [non-strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), in which `this` is set to global object if it's not received by a function.

Comment: When I said that removing the `import` statement "worked" I meant that it was no longer undefined. I had only been testing for undefined or not, and added the output of the type name at the last minute - and failed to notice that it was not the same as the others. Sorry. I still don't see why adding/removing the import turns strict mode on or off though!

Comment: This could be an artefact of how the build/run tools are set up when compiling your code on StackBlitz. Browsers [turn strict mode on](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules) for scripts loaded with `type="module"` attribute. The StackBlitz environment might be adding this attribute to javascript files which contain `import` or `export` statements, or it can load it as normal script (not module) but add "use strict;" to emulate browser behavior for modules.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be "environmental", which is unfortunate because I was using a StackBlitz to strip everything back to the bare minimum to *remove* anything that was specific to my real code. I hadn't counted on something like this, and it makes me nervous about using StackBlitz for this sort of thing.

Comment: Well, if your code is TypeScript, then you can't really run your code, you have to compile it and also maybe use module bundler/loader in addition to the compiler if you want to run modular code in all browsers; which makes everything environment-specific. (see for example [--alwaysStrict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler option which may also affect this).

Comment: To paraphrase your answer by quoting MDN: "When a function is called as a method of an object [e.g. `foo.method()`], its `this` is set to the object the method is called on." but with method 3 `foo.method` is *referenced* without being invoked in that way, and so `this` is not set (or is set to the `globalThis` object). I think I get that - thanks.